# Can anyone help me out on a form spamming issue?

Tags: forms, spam-prevention

I have a form for enquiries on my website.
Spammers are using it to keep sending me SEO and dating links.
I want to stop this.
They aways enter "google" in the company name field before submitting the form.

Is there an easy way to send these spammers on to my "thankyou" page on submit, so they think they have successfully spammed me but in effect nothing has happened?

Basically - if submitted companyname field = google then on submit do not send form results by email but just present thankyou.html page.

My page is here [here is my contact form](https://www.insight-software-training.co.uk/quote.htm)

Comment: The solution depends on the logic you've implemented on the server. One approach is to check the `companyName` field in backend code and if condition is found to be true, just go to the part where you render "Thank you" page. Otherwise, send a mail or whatever you do for a valid inquiry.

Comment: Thanks for that but I cannot access the cgi folder. I hoped to be able to check the companyname field and decide on that using Javascript.

Comment: Okay, you can write logic inside your `formCheck()` function that `if (alertMsg.length === l_Msg && companyName === "google")`, then redirect to `https://www.insight-software-training.co.uk/confirm.htm`. Otherwise, `return true` to proceed as a valid entry.

Comment: Thanks for this Ajay. Where would I paste this in and what exactly would the code be? I am no good at coding so please keep it dead simple!

Comment: You're welcome. Also, I also sent a spam email with id something like `1@1.com`. Forgive me for that. I just did that to get link of "Thank you" page to post here. I'll post the code as an answer in a bit.

Comment: I thought it was you! Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followup from the comments section.

Inside your `formCheck()` function, replace this piece of code

```js
if (alertMsg.length == l_Msg){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(alertMsg);
    return false;
}
```

with

```js
if (alertMsg.length == l_Msg){ // No alerts
    let companyName = formobj.elements['Company'].value || "";
    if(companyName.trim().toLowerCase()==='google'){ // Potential spam, redirect to "Thank you" page.
        window.location.href='confirm.htm'
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, proceed as valid entry.
    return true;
}else{
    alert(alertMsg);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! It works really well. Many thanks for helping me out! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I still seem to be getting spam mail using company=google despite your fix. Have I entered your code correctly?

Comment: You have `companyName==='google'` in yours, whereas I have written `companyName.trim().toLowerCase()==='google'`. `trim()` function removes whitespaces around the string, so `"google "`,`" google "`,`" google"` all reduces to `"google"`. `toLowerCase()` converts the string to all lowercase characters. Can you provide the **exact** company name in the spam mail you received. I think they may just have put some extra space or something.

Comment: here it is:REMOTE_HOST: 185.104.187.115

HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299

name: Adult online dÐ°ting ÐµÑ…changing numbers: http://xsle.net/sexywoman880359

Company: google

telephone: 88174851425

postcode: 132433

Main-site: From Main Site

email_: tsaxma@yahoo.com

software-: -----------------------------------------------

delegates_number: 4 or 5

extra_info: Adult dating american guÑƒs onlinÐµ: https://bogazicitente.com/sexywoman99510

Submit:  Send form

Comment: First, change `companyName==='google'` to `companyName.trim().toLowerCase()==='google'`. Now, try submitting a fake form with `company=google` yourself. If it still doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: Lovely! That change seems to work!  Thanks very much again!

Comment: You're welcome. If you still get spam mail, let me know here.

Comment: It's still happening. I'm still getting spam mail. I don't know how they are managing to bypass your script check. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, now there can be two scenarios: 1. Since the spammers have access to client-side code, they can change it to bypass the logic. 2. The spammers are not using the form given on the website for submission, they are directly making a POST request to your server route.

Comment: The solution to both of these scenarios is to write validation logic on the server-side. I suggested this in my very first comment on your post but you insisted to do it on the client-side. Client-side validation is never reliable since it can be easily bypassed. That's why you must have a server-side validation.

Comment: Fair enough. So basically I cannot do anything about it as I cannot run server side code. Many thanks for trying to solve this issue. I will just have to put up with it!

Comment: `I cannot run server side code`, aren't you the admin of the website?

Comment: I am but as my site is hosted by one.com I cannot access the cgi folder.

Comment: As I said, without server-side validation, it's hard to achieve a reliable validation based on client-side code. I'm sorry but maybe you just have to put up with it. Don't you have a spam filter in One.com Webmail?

Comment: Spam filter is on but doesn't stop people spamming the form as you have seen. The Spam filter is basic and is either off or on - no subleties.